# Can the mass of a proton be measured through algebra?

Tags: lie-algebras, physics

I found a paper called the Absolute Relativity Theory and I thought it was intriguing. (Link: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.2562v1.pdf)

The authors claim they can measure the mass of the proton / neutron and electron using only algebra.
They also claim they can predict the existence of particles not yet found, and also give their characteristics.

Does anyone know if this idea that mass can be calculated algebraically is present in other theories ?
Is this theory widespread within the mathematical (or physical) community ?

Comment: Shouldn't this be in the Physics section? It is, after all, a "physics" paper.

Comment: Regardless, papers like this are usually heavily scrutinized in the physics community. Invariably, one of two things happens: 1.) The theory presents no new testable predictions, and so is not useful, or 2.) The theory is wrong in some way or another that has already been confirmed by experiment.

Comment: This type of question may be genuine (when it probably should be posted at Physics.SE), or it is an attempt to bait people into clicking a link and/or to view something. Anyway, for the question to be interesting you should at least justify your choice of tags somehow. Yes, in elementary particly physics Lie-algebras and their representations play a large role, but the standard models usually need to leave a few parameters to be measured. If the paper introduces new ways of tying the parameters of the standard model together, that would be great.

Comment: (cont'd) But, the expertise to judge the value of an arXiv submission is not here. Anyway, your post bears many of the earmarks of someone trying to draw attention to something they have authored themselves. We have seen a few too many of those. I don't know if that is the case here. I don't really care. If my vote were not immediately binding I would vote to close this as off-topic.

Comment: I'm glad it was left open, as that was fun. ;)

Comment: It is nice food for the holidays. If I compare such a paper to one of Einstein's great papers, it is far too full of too complex stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I admittedly didn't read the category theory-based sections carefully (mostly because I don't know nearly enough category theory to actually judge their results fairly), but the end results are what you're asking about anyway, so let's talk about those (i.e. section III).

Unfortunately, all of the author's calculations are too far off from the actual values of things for the theory to hold any water. The calculated age of the universe (18.18 Gyr, given without uncertainty) is significantly different from the measured age ($13.799\pm.021$ Gyr). Since this age is also used in the calculation of $G$, those results are also thrown into question. The authors explain this away as bias based on faulty assumptions about constancy of constants, but they cannot do the same for later calculations.

The authors report a .0007% discrepancy between the calculated mass of the proton and its measured counterpart, or a relative error of $7\times 10^{-5}$. The mass of the proton has been measured to a precision of $2\times 10^{-8}$, so they are reporting a discrepancy that is *one thousand times larger* than experimental error. They report no biases here, claiming that the closeness to the experimental result proves their theory correct. Instead of confirming their theory, this unforgivably large discrepancy damns it.

Similarly, the calculated masses of the muon and tau lepton (which they call the "electron $\mu$" and "electron $\tau$") are also at odds with experimental results. The authors obtain a value of $105.9$ MeV/c^2 for the muon mass, whereas the actual measured muon mass is $105.6583745\pm.0000024$ MeV/c^2. The discrepancy here is on the order of $3\times 10^{-3}$, which is, *one hundred thousand times larger* than the experimental uncertainty of $2\times 10^{-8}$, an even worse discrepancy than before.

The tau lepton mass is calculated by the authors to be $1.82146$ GeV/c^2, whereas the measured value is $1.77682\pm .00016$ GeV/c^2. Relative error on the calculated value is $2.5\times 10^{-2}$, and the relative uncertainty on the measured value is $9\times 10^{-5}$. Once again, the discrepancy between theory and experiment is *hundreds of times larger* than the uncertainty in experiment.

My verdict? This theory does not predict anywhere near the correct values for the physical constants, even when the authors said it did. Therefore, it cannot be an accurate description of reality.

Comment: It would be nice to have some mathematical structure identified, which would contain approximations to masses, gives the proper zoo of particles etc just out of its properties. So getting the mass of the proton with 1% error is not that bad. Alas I suspect that it is not worth putting time into understanding their method, as I expect that they put in that mass into their theory at some point in a more or less hard to decipher way.